# C: Malloc Assertion Failed

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I recently started learning C and was writing some application, I am getting this error which I have never seen before and which apparently am getting when I am mallocing

`malloc.c:2394: Assertion (old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0) failed.
Aborted (core dumped)`

Here is the code snippet

```
typedef struct {
    Node *root;
    pthread_id id;
    pid_t tid;
}Thread;

typedef struct {
    Thread **thread;
    int cap, len;
}arr;

static __thread Thread *self = NULL;
pthread_mutex_t lock;
static arr p;

static void 
foo (void)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    Thread **newthread;
    if (p.len == p.cap){
        if (p.cap != 0){
            newthread = (Thread **) realloc(p.thread, (1+p.cap)*sizeof(Thread *));
        }
        else {
            newthread = (Thread **)malloc(sizeof(Thread *));
        }
        if (!newthread){
            printf("appendThreadpointer: Error while allocating size\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        p.thread=newthread;
        ++p.cap;
    }

    ++p.len;
    Thread *t = malloc(sizeof(Thread *));
    t->tid = syscall(SYS_gettid);
    t->root = newNode();
    t->id = pthread_self();
    p.thread[p.len-1] = t;
    self = t;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

can anyone see the reason why this could be happening? and the most weird thing is if I remove `tid` field from `Thread` struct then it works fine, it only gives me this error when I include `tid` field.

Am confused, Any help on this would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: `Thread *t = malloc(sizeof(Thread *));` -- This looks fishy. You allocate space for a pointer to thread, but you need space for a thread: `Thread *t = malloc(sizeof(Thread));` or better yet, `Thread *t = malloc(sizeof(*t));`. (The error you get could be related that by under-allocating `t` and thus writing out of bounds later, you corrupt the C lib's householding data for the dynamic memory.)

Comment: ohh man, such a stupid mistake, yes you are right, Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Thread *t = malloc(sizeof(Thread *));
```

probably should be changed to

```
Thread *t = malloc(sizeof(Thread));
```

Comment: Getting into the habit of writing mallocs as `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr))` will save you lots of grief.  (This is better IMHO than `sizeof(Thread)` or whatever ptr is declared as, as it continues to be correct if you change the storage class of ptr).